# Check value of last line selected - vscode-api

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to figure out how to see if the active editor's last line that's selected contains any characters/text excluding spaces. The purpose of this is to identify if there are any text highlighted and if not then to go back up a number in the editor and not include that line.

I know that you can do this

```
        const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor
        const lastLineSelected = editor.selection.end
```

in order to get the last line number, but how can I evaluate the text that's highlighted in that line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to get the text of the last line of a selection which may be multi-line.  The below does that, with a check in case the only selected line is partially selected.

```
const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
const selection = editor.selection;

if (selection && !selection?.isEmpty) {

    // is more than one line selected, if so use 0 as the start of the selection on the last line
    //  otherwise use the actual first character selected on that line
    const firstSelectedCharacterOnLastLine = (selection.start.line < selection.end.line) ? 0 : selection.start.character;

    // make a Range to use with getText(<some Range>)
    const lastLineOfSelectionRange = new vscode.Range(selection.end.line, firstSelectedCharacterOnLastLine, selection.end.line, selection.end.character);

    const text = editor.document.getText(lastLineOfSelectionRange);

    // do your testing on the text using javascript String methods
    // like text.search(/[^\s]/)  search for any non-whitespace character
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was super helpful!